# Android(device mode) sending bulk data to host

Tags: android, usb

When Android is in slave mode, it has big amount of data to send to host, when it sends each packet to the out endpoint via file outputstream, does it need wait for any signal from the host?

I tried sending about 115K bytes from the Android to Windows, packed each packet to 512 bytes before calling output stream written method, I found many packets were lost from host side view, my Windows host side instantiated the asynchronous transfer mode.

If I send small data message (less than 256 bytes) between the Windows and the Android device, it works pretty well from both side, but when I send big trunk of data, I always have many lost packets.

Comment: Looks what I need is that, when the host submit transfer for the data request, what kind of related signal in Android side which pass the notification to the app.

Comment: After several tuning, I added video frame data verification on both Android side and Windows PC side, now the video on PC side is very smooth now, basically what we need is to carefully define the data transfer protocol.